# DRIVER ERROR SQL EXCEPTION java and ms access

Tags: java, jdbc, odbc, driver

This is the runtime error I encounter while running my program (I use MS Access as a database).

```
SQl Exception
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft
Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=PayRoll.mdb;DriverID=22;READONLY=true)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at clsConnection.setConnection(clsConnection.java:35)
        at LoginFrame.login(LoginFrame.java:122)
        at LoginFrame.actionPerformed(LoginFrame.java:106)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
SQl Exception
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft
Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=PayRoll.mdb;DriverID=22;READONLY=true)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at clsConnection.setConnection(clsConnection.java:35)
        at LoginFrame.login(LoginFrame.java:122)
        at LoginFrame.actionPerformed(LoginFrame.java:106)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have "MakeDB.ini" file which has this code:

```
jdbc.drivers=sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=PayRoll.mdb;DriverID=22;READONLY=true) 
jdbc.username=""
jdbc.password=""
```

In this case, what should be the "DATA SOURCE NAME" in data source(odbc)

This is my code:  LoginFrame.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Date;

public class LoginFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    static JFrame frame;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private static JFrame loginFrame;
    private static JPanel panel1;
    private static JPanel panel2;
    private static JPanel panel3;
    private JButton loginBtn;
    private JButton exitBtn;
    int dialogtype = JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE;
    String dialogmessage;
    String dialogs;
    private JLabel nameLbl;
    private JLabel userLbl;
    private JLabel passwordLbl;
    private static JTextField userTxt;
    private static JPasswordField passwordTxt;

    public String loginname;
    public String loginpass;

    // class Veriables
    clsConnection connect = new clsConnection();
    //Connection variable

    Connection conn;
        Dimension screen    =   Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

    static Date td          = new Date();   

    public LoginFrame()
    {


   panel1 = new JPanel();
   panel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
   nameLbl = new JLabel("WELCOME TO GEC'S PAYROLL SYSTEM");

   panel2 = new JPanel();
   panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
   userLbl = new JLabel("Username :");
   userTxt = new JTextField(20);

   passwordLbl = new JLabel("Password :");

   passwordTxt = new JPasswordField(20);

   panel3 = new JPanel();
   panel3.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

   loginBtn = new JButton("Login", new ImageIcon("images/key.gif"));

   loginBtn.addActionListener(this);
   exitBtn = new JButton("Exit", new ImageIcon("images/Keys.gif"));

   exitBtn.addActionListener(this);
    panel1.add(nameLbl);
    panel1.setOpaque(true);
    panel2.add(userLbl);
    panel2.add(userTxt);
    panel2.add(passwordLbl);
    panel2.add(passwordTxt);
    panel2.setOpaque(true);
    panel3.add(loginBtn);
    panel3.add(exitBtn);
    panel3.setOpaque(true);
    frame = new JFrame("PayRoll User Login...");
       frame.setSize(300,200);

    Container pane = frame.getContentPane();   
    pane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    //pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
    pane.add(panel1);
    pane.add(panel2);
    pane.add(panel3);
    frame.setLocation((screen.width - 500)/2,((screen.height-350)/2));  
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
        {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });



    }

       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        Object source = event.getSource();
        if(source.equals(loginBtn))
        {
           login();

        } 
        else if(source.equals(exitBtn))
        {
                    System.exit(0);
        }
    }

        public void login()
        {
            loginname = userTxt.getText().trim();
            loginpass = passwordTxt.getText().trim();


            try {
                conn = connect.setConnection(conn,"","");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
            }
            try{


                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

                String query = "SELECT * FROM Login WHERE USERNAME='" + loginname + 
                        "'AND PASSWORD='"+loginpass+"'";
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                boolean recordfound = rs.next();
                if (recordfound)
                {

                    dialogmessage = "Welcome - " +loginname;
                    dialogtype = JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component)null, dialogmessage, dialogs, dialogtype);
                    userTxt.setText("");
                    passwordTxt.setText("");
                    frame.setVisible(false);
                    frame.dispose();
                    MainMenu menu = new MainMenu(loginname,td);


                }
                else
                {
                    dialogmessage = "Login Failed!";
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INVALID ID OR PASSWORD!",
                            "WARNING!!",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

                    userTxt.setText("");
                    passwordTxt.setText("");
                }
                conn.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
          {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"GENERAL EXCEPTION", "WARNING!!!",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }       
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        LoginFrame frame1 = new LoginFrame();
        frame1.addNotify();
        frame1.pack();


    }



}
```

clsConnection.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;


public class clsConnection {
        String url = "";
        String username = "";
        String password = "";


    public Connection setConnection(Connection conn, String username, String password )

    {
        try
    {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        String fileName = "MakeDB.ini";
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        props.load(in);
        String drivers = props.getProperty("jdbc.drivers");
        if(drivers != null)
        System.setProperty("jdbc.drivers", drivers);
         url = props.getProperty("jdbc.url");
         username = props.getProperty("jdbc.username");
         password = props.getProperty("jdbc.password");
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);

    }catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.err.println("SQl Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

           catch(IOException e)
           {
               System.out.println("\nIO Exception");
           }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("\nAnother Error");
            }
            return conn;

    }




}
```

how to connect to db in control panel >>administrative>>data source odbc >>what will be dsn in this case

Comment: Could you post your clsConnection class?

Comment: Java's JDBC-ODBC Bridge is essentially obsolete. An alternative is described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390). Does that help?